# ffmpeg to convert all .jpg to mp4

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have a folder that has about 10,000 separate jpegs in it, and I want to take all of these and convert them into one single mp4 video.  When I do

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -pattern_type glob -i '/media/e/serv01/Dorgem/camera_history/$f_date/*.jpg' -c:v libx264 /media/e/serv01/Dorgem/camera_history/$f_date/$f_date.mp4
```

from terminal it works fine, but once I put this into a bash script I get an error that it can't find *.jpg

Comment: Show us your bash script.

Comment: If `$f_date` is a shell variable that you want expanded then you cannot use single quotes; use double quotes instead.

Comment: Unrelated: your output will also use `-r 1`, but this may not work on "dumb" players, so you may need to add an `-r` option for the output as well.

Comment: Quoting is good so following mark4o's suggestion you should quote your other argument as well: `ffmpeg -r 1 -pattern_type glob -i "/media/e/serv01/Dorgem/camera_history/$f_date/*.jpg" -c:v libx264 "/media/e/serv01/Dorgem/camera_history/$f_date/$f_date.mp4"`

Answer (score 0):

I tried executing ffmpeg on Ubuntu 13.10 for doing exactly that but it started complaining with all sorts of errors. It seems ffmpeg is deprecated by avconv. Here is how I compiled my JPEGs into an .mp4 using avconv:

```
avconv -r 30 -i line-%06d.jpg -qscale 2 -r 30 out.mp4
```

What I was trying to do is create a video of panning across a huge JPEG. If anyone's interested, details are here:
[Video panning across your family tree chart (.jpg to .mp4)](http://www.electronicsfaq.com/2013/12/video-panning-across-your-family-tree.html)

Comment: Arg, no no no, FFMpeg is not deprecated by avconv. There has been a fork that lead to two competing projects, FFMpeg and Libav, and Ubuntu made the controversial choice to force users to use avconv even when running a 'ffmpeg' binary. See http://blog.pkh.me/p/13-the-ffmpeg-libav-situation.html

Comment: @SirDarius wow! did not know that!! thanks for correcting me and pointing out the real story!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it working. The video is 3 second long, in `mp4` format. This works well with different scales of images.

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i input.jpg -vf "scale=1024:-2" -c:v libx264 -t 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 output.mp4`

Explanation

`-loop 1`: indefinitely loop the input file

`-framerate 1`: the input image will be treated as if it's a 1 fps video.

`-vf "scale=1024:-2"`: Applies a video filter with the scale filter.

`-c:v libx264`: codec to use for encoding the video stream

`-t 3`: video of 3 seconds.

`-pix_fmt yuv420p`: pixel format

`-r 25`: This sets the frame rate for the output video